# Error Message Occurs in Saving Excel Files when I use Excel VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to save the below code it gives an error message and I can't save it.

below are my error message's image file link.
I'm using Korean Excel 2007, So I don't know what exactly this message is in English but I can give you the meaning of this error message.

[(this error message means... couldn't find file.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGT71.jpg)

[(this error message means.... &H8000FFFF system error occurs.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QHGn.jpg)

[(I tried Export UserForm File but there were same error messages.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJRVA.jpg)

I tried opening another Excel Window and Pasting Userforms, exporting Userform as files, saving as a different name and saving to a different path, but I kept getting the same error message.

I updated My windows7 to latest version in several days ago.

Below is part of code for sending Email From Excel (All code couldn't upload. It is so long and considered as spam.) and I uploaded UserForm ScreenShots For your Reference.

-----------My Part of Code And UserForm

[My UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5sJk.jpg)

```
Function NPP메일보내기함수()

    '//ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Date & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51 '//xlsm은 52
    '//위 방법은 xlsx 저장은 잘 되나 아래와 같은 문제가 있다.
    '//I have a Excel sheet, and if I save the file using the Save as... option in Excel VBA the currently open document would close, and switch over to the newly created document.
    '//How can I save a copy of the document without switching over the control?
    '//해결하려면 여러가지 방법이 있다. 여기엔 하나만 적는다. 아래와 같이 하는건 잘못된 방법이다. SaveCopyAS는 확장자 못 바꿈.
    '//ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Date & " " & "Position Report Ver.2 MEIN.xlsx" '//, FileFormat:=51
    '//위 방법은 새창으로 안 열리기는 하나 확장자가 안 바뀜.
    '//아래 방법이 새창으로 안 열리면서 확장자도 바뀌는 완벽한 방법임.

'
'    Dim wb As Workbook, pstr As String
'
'    pstr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Date & " Position Report Ver. 02 MEIN" & ".xlsm"
'    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=y
'
'    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(pstr)
'    wb.SaveAs Left(pstr, Len(pstr) - 1) & "x", 52
'    wb.Close False
'
'    Kill pstr
'    오류뜸

    '//http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/save-workbook-as-new-file.shtml


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim 매크로파일경로 As String
    매크로파일경로 = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs 매크로파일경로 & "\눈레포트 첨부 엑셀파일\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "Position Report Ver.3 MEIN.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close


    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oOutlook        As Object
    Dim sAPPPath        As String

    If IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application") = True Then    'Outlook was already running
        Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    Else    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        sAPPPath = GetAppExePath("outlook.exe")    'determine outlook's installation path
        Shell (sAPPPath)    'start outlook
        Do While Not IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application")
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    End If

    '    MsgBox "Outlook Should be running now, let's do something"
    Const olMailItem = 0
    Dim oOutlookMsg     As Object
    Set oOutlookMsg = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)    'Start a new e-mail message

    Dim 보낼메세지 As String
    Dim 반복문카운터 As Integer
    For 반복문카운터 = 95 To 127
        보낼메세지 = 보낼메세지 & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NPP").Range("C" & 반복문카운터).Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    Next
    With oOutlookMsg
        .To = "해사운항팀"
        .CC = " 사업안전팀; 최종범차장; 조달팀; 공무팀; 사업팀; 박준영대리; 고현해운"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("C99").Value
        '// .Body = Range("C95:C127").Value 요렇게 하면 안돼요.
        .Body = 보낼메세지
        '//Attachments를 Attachment라고 써서 에러가 나던 것.
        .Attachments.Add 매크로파일경로 & "\눈레포트 첨부 엑셀파일\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "Position Report Ver.3 MEIN.xlsx"
        '//ThisWorkbook.Path하니까 파일이 없다는 오류가 나서 시도해봄.
        .Display    'Show the message to the user
    End With


Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: StartOutlook" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : IsAppRunning
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Determine is an App is running or not
' Copyright : The following may be altered and reused as you wish so long as the
'             copyright notice is left unchanged (including Author, Website and
'             Copyright).  It may not be sold/resold or reposted on other sites (links
'             back to this site are allowed).
'
' Input Variables:
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' sApp      : GetObject Application to verify if it is running or not
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application")
' IsAppRunning("Excel.Application")
' IsAppRunning("Word.Application")
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2014-Oct-31                 Initial Release
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function IsAppRunning(sApp As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oApp            As Object

    Set oApp = GetObject(, sApp)
    IsAppRunning = True

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetAppExePath
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Determine the path for a given exe installed on the local computer
' Copyright : The following may be altered and reused as you wish so long as the
'             copyright notice is left unchanged (including Author, Website and
'             Copyright).  It may not be sold/resold or reposted on other sites (links
'             back to this site are allowed).
'
' Input Variables:
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' sEXEName  : Name of the exe to locate
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' Call GetAppExePath("msaccess.exe")
' GetAppExePath("firefox.exe")
' GetAppExePath("outlook.exe")
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2014-Oct-31                 Initial Release
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetAppExePath(ByVal sExeName As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim WSHShell        As Object

    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    GetAppExePath = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & sExeName & "\")

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WSHShell = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = -2147024894 Then
        'Cannot locate requested exe????
    Else
        MsgBox "The following error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: GetAppExePath" & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
               vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook` has never been saved, `ThisWorkbook.Path` is `""`.  Also, in your code, you never set `y` to anything, yet you try to save a file with name `y`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my code's saving function is working well in before. it is more related with excel program itself. not the code's problem.

Comment: I think there may be too much of a language problem for me to help you.  But if your program cannot find the file, then the file was not saved with the name you expect.  UserForm runs code.

Comment: Thank you Ron, But its not my code's problem maybe, the error message pops up in excel itself. I'm using excel's saving function, not vba's saving function...

Comment: this is my error log.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">

<logFileName>error099640_01.xml</logFileName>

<summary>'E:\MEGA INNOVATION DATA\삼항사\001 ★삼항사 실무폴더★\006 매일\Position_Report (ver 03).xlsm' 파일에 오류가 있습니다.</summary>


-<additionalInfo>

<info>파일이 심하게 손상되어 복구할 수 없습니다. Excel에서 수식과 값을 저장하려고 했지만 일부 데이터가 손실되거나 손상된 것 같습니다.</info>

</additionalInfo>

</recoveryLog>

Comment: excel file usually recovers itself, but this time it can't recover itself... weird